# Eclipse plugin for working with protobuf

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, protocol-buffers

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (protobuf) are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format.

There's [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-netbeans-plugin/) for Netbeans, but I cannot find one for Eclipse. Does it exist? If yes, please, share the link.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the plugin to do?  Edit files in a nice way?  Build them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using Google's "Protocol Buffers Development Tools". It is a plugin for Eclipse that features automagic regeneration and error checking with quick fixes, among other things.
It's available here: https://github.com/google/protobuf-dt/blob/master/README.md .

Comment: Your link is broken; I went looking, but had little luck finding a working download location.

Comment: Thanjs @kd8azz I fixed the link.

Comment: An alternate link is: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/protocol-buffers

Answer (score 2):

It does [not seem to be approved by Eclipse yet](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/higgins-dev/msg05454.html).
And the [EMF project uses protobuf](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.emf/msg39525.html), but not as a plugin.

So for now, no there do not seem to be any Eclipse protobuf plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried protobuf-dt, that was the only plugin [on marketplace]. But it had some issues, so I created (November 2016) one that would fit protobuf and gRPC usage, that we have ([generation inside maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426366/automatically-generate-java-from-proto-with-maven-m2e-in-eclipse-ide) without waiting for [issues](https://github.com/google/protobuf-dt/issues) to be solved)

Welcome minimalist editor for .proto files. Just 25KB, works in any Eclipse (latest protobuf-dt 3.2 requires Neon)
Sources and notes are at
https://github.com/Enide/polyglot-maven-editors#minimalist-proto-files-editor-for-protocol-buffers-and-grpc

It is already on Marketplace https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/minimalist-proto-files-editor-protocol-buffers-and-grpc

[image]

Comment: Is not available anymore.

Comment: Yes, binaries are away as BinTray is down. But it is possible to build locally with maven, and install from produced update site archive 
https://github.com/Enide/polyglot-maven-editors/blob/master/README.md#using

Answer (score 1):

Using m2eclipse and directions from [Issue 81/Comment 6](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=81#c6) for a a protobuf maven plugin, it works pretty well.

The only trick that doesn't work exactly is the "generated-sources/protobuf" will be created following the instructions is not automatically added to source folder in eclipse. Do this manually and you're g2g.

Related Stackoverflow Issues:

- [how-do-i-get-support-for-gpb-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144011/how-do-i-get-support-for-gpb-in-eclipse)
- [integrate-protocol-buffers-into-maven2-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578456/integrate-protocol-buffers-into-maven2-build)