# How do I get support for GPB in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use Google Protocol Buffers in my project and I'd like to have some tooling support from Eclipse. In particular, I want Eclipse to call `protoc` every time I make changes to the `.proto` files and then rebuild all code that depends on the generated code.

I tried to set up a Custom Builder but it keeps bugging me with errors I don't understand, most often it complains that the `.proto` file is not on the path given by `--proto-path`, which it should be by all I can tell. Also, because I use `${build_files}`, Eclipse passes all changed files to the compiler (instead of those that I have configured to trigger the build).

NetBeans seems to have a protobuf-Plugin, but I can't find one for Eclipse. Is there one?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968578/eclipse-plugin-for-working-with-protobuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, syntax highlighting turned out to not be that important, I hardly edit these files, and they tend to be very small. Maven and the m2eclipse plugin handle the building side of things great.

Answer (score 3):

Theres a protoclipse plugin on googlecode, which is in the initial stages:
http://code.google.com/p/protoclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a builder, but I did find a plugin for [syntax highlighting](http://arno.blogger.de/stories/1191168/) for protocol buffers.

You can define an [external builder](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_an_external_builder_on_my_source_files%3F) on the plugin that invokes an ant task. It is an ugly kludge, but until there is a better solution this may serve your purposes.

Comment: Yup, this is what use as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Google's "Protocol Buffers Development Tools". It is a plugin for Eclipse that features automagic regeneration and error checking, among other things. It's available here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt/ .

Answer (score 0):

While this question is close to other [Eclipse plugin for working with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968578/eclipse-plugin-for-working-with-protobuf),  answers here are different.

Well, yes, if you use maven/gradle to invoke `protoc` (Protobuf compiler), than you may need no Eclipse plugin at all.
Colorizing editor helps for long file or with many comments. Know there are 2 editor plugins for Eclipse.