# How to add protocol buffers support to a maven project ?

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

How to integrate protocol buffers with a maven project ? Couldn't find any information for maven users on the [protocol buffers page](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html). I need to add PB support to my web app project with protoc compiler support as well for maven, if it is there.

Comment: Is this covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578456/integrate-protocol-buffers-into-maven2-build ?

Comment: Thanks Marc! this helps .. i chose this snippet to integrate with PB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578456/integrate-protocol-buffers-into-maven2-build/3007010#3007010 just a question.. how do i specify the location of protoc compiler here as my buld fails saying it cant locate protoc. is that provided by the protobuf 2.4.1 jar that is added by adding a dependency or do I need to keep it separately in my code ? where is it located if it is there ? thanks!

Comment: cool no problem.. i just supplied it manually and it works.. will there be any issue if i change versions of protobuf but not the protoc, if you can tell ?

Comment: You either make sure the PATH includes the dir containing protoc, or you can specify the location in the pom.xml - search for `<protocExecutable>` on [this page](https://github.com/dtrott/maven-protoc-plugin) for an example.